# Which Java EE server for our project?

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jetty

We're going to start a student project based on

- Java EE
- Spring
- Hibernate
- REST
- probably EJB methods via SOAP (between two servers)
- maybe GWT.

We're wondering which serwer is best for our project. We can use Glassfish which has everything specified in Java EE 6, or for example Jetty with additional libraries like Jersey. It is important for us, that server could be in future used commercially.

What is the best choice for us?

Answer (score 1):

Glassfish. Oracle has it, until Java goes down, glassfish definitely won't.

Of course, it doesn't much matter what server you use, as long as it fills your purpose, and glassfish does that well.

Comment: But performance and scalability may be different in Jetty vs Glassfish?

Answer (score 0):

I used a lot JBoss AS and it's nice and free.